# Cross-Domain JQuery Ajax call to WCF Service with BasicHttpbinding

Tags: jquery

I have a WCF service with  "BasicHttpbinding" binding in place.I can gracefully call the service using JQuery in Internet Explorer. But the same code does not work in Chrome or FireFox. I can understand there is a Cross-Domain issue with JQuery Ajax call from Chrome or FireFox. I know I can expose a "webHttpBinding" binding with crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" and call the service. But if there is a scanario that , I have to go with the existing "BasicHttp" binding then what is the solution? I have called the WCF service with the following JQuery code:

```
      $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "http://localhost:1415/MyService.svc/bh/",
                  data: bhRequest,
                  timeout: 10000,
                  contentType: "text/xml",
                  dataType: "xml",
                  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                      xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IMyService/GetData");
                  },
                  success: function (data) {
                      $(data).find("GetDataResponse").each(function () {
                          alert($(this).find("GetDataResult").text());
                      });
                  },
                  error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                      alert(error);

                  }
              });
```

My WCF service method is as following:

```
 [OperationContract]
 string GetData(int value);
```

Could anybody provide any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

Add global.asax to your WCF and afterwards add this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
}
```